# Why isn't this displaying the ' admin' page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, meanjs

I was reading the MEAN MACHINE Book and was following its instructions under 
Routing Node applications [ pg - 36]

> The express.Router()⁴⁸ acts as a mini application. You can call an instance of it (like we do for Express)
>   and then define routes on that. Let’s look at an example so we know exactly what this means. Add
>   this to your ‘server.js’ file if you’d like to follow along.
>   Underneath our app.get() route inside of server.js, add the following. We’ll 1. call an instance
>   of the router 2. apply routes to it 3. and then add those routes to our main app

Accordingly I copy-pasted the code [ pls see below] 
http://localhost:1337/admin
Page throws an error saying  " Cannnot GET/admin "

Code :

```
// load the express package and create our app
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

// send our index.html file to the user for the home page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

// create routes for the admin section
// get an instance of the router
var adminRouter = express.Router();
// route middleware that will happen on every request
// admin main page. the dashboard (http://localhost:1337/admin)
adminRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('I am the dashboard!');
});

// users page (http://localhost:1337/admin/users)
adminRouter.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.send('I show all the users!');
});

// posts page (http://localhost:1337/admin/posts)
adminRouter.get('/posts', function(req, res) {
    res.send('I show all the posts!');
    // apply the routes to our application
    app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
}); 

// start the server
app.listen(1337);
console.log('1337 is the magic port!');
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `app.use('/admin', adminRouter);` adds the adminRouter to the main application.

You have that **inside** the function that gets called for `/posts` on that router.

Consequently, it never gets called.

You need to move it down so it appears between `});` and `// start the server`

Answer (score 0):

```
     adminRouter.get('/posts', function(req, res) {
     res.send('I show all the posts!');

    // apply the routes to our application
    app.use('/admin', adminRouter);

 });
```

Use app.use outside the middleware.

```
    adminRouter.get('/posts', function(req, res) {
      res.send('I show all the posts!');
    })
  // apply the routes to our application
    app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
```